# Modulus of continuity of Radial Basis Function

Tags: machine-learning, uniform-continuity, neural-networks

Let the Gaussian RBF be defined by $f(\vec{x}) = w e^{-\gamma||\vec{x} - \vec{c}||_2^2}$ for $\vec{x} \in [0,1]^d$. Are there any result on the modulus of continuity for this function? and other types of RBF (e.g. inverse quadratic)?